# Convert result from groupby on multiple columns to list of dictionaries of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to convert result from pandas groupby function to a array of dictionaries of dictionaries.

Code run:

```
df = df.groupby(['DE', 'SW', 'Tech'])['COUNT(*)'].sum()
```

Output:

```
DE          SW  Tech  
2021-01-01  s1  t1          1
2021-04-02  s1  t1        699
                t2        268
2021-04-06  s1  t1          2
            s2  t1        466
                t2         81
                t3        954
Name: COUNT(*), Length: 474, dtype: int64
```

Expected output:

```
[
  {'2021-01-01': {'s1':{'t1': 1}} },
  {'2021-04-02': {'s1':{'t1': 699, 't2': 268}} },
  {'2021-04-06': {'s1':{'t1': 2}, 's2':{'t1': 466,'t2': 81,'t3': 954}} },
]
```

I tried using `reset_index` and then `set_index('DE')` but that throws an error due to non unique index. Using multiple values in `set_index` doesn't give the required output either.

Note: the columns used in `df.groupby` can also increase or decrease.

Please advice on how to achieve the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try defining a function `dictify` that takes the input argument as the multiindex pandas series and return the nested dictionary in the required format

```
def dictify(s):
    if s.index.nlevels == 1: return s.to_dict()
    return {k: dictify(g.droplevel(0)) for k, g in s.groupby(level=0)}

records = [{k: v} for k, v in dictify(df).items()]
```

---

```
>>> df

DE          SW  Tech  
2021-01-01  s1  t1          1
2021-04-02  s1  t1        699
                t2        268
2021-04-06  s1  t1          2
            s2  t1        466
                t2         81
                t3        954
Name: COUNT(*), Length: 474, dtype: int64

>>> records

[{'2021-01-01': {'s1': {'t1': 1}}},
 {'2021-04-02': {'s1': {'t1': 699, 't2': 268}}},
 {'2021-04-06': {'s1': {'t1': 2}, 's2': {'t1': 466, 't2': 81, 't3': 954}}}]
```